# JavaScript command getSelection is not working whereas getElementById is working fine

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to enter text in textbox through JavaScript command but I am facing an strange situation where CSS locator is not working to update text but ID locator is able to do that.

URl : https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fpc%3Dcarousel-about-en

Here is my Screen shot of Browser Console for both command result:

1. With getSelection
   [Image of getSelection JavaScript Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOyZj.png)
2. with getElementByID
   [Image of getElementByID JavaScript Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBkEw.png)

I tried to check same in Selenium but getting same issue. getElementByID is entering text in field but getSelection not.

Please help me to understand reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getSelection` isn't used to select nodes in the html page, it's used to [select highlighted text on the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getSelection).

I believe what you're looking for is `window.document.querySelector` . I tried the following on that page and it worked fine.

```
window.document.querySelector("#FirstName").value = 'Praveen';
```

Comment: My apologize. Yes, I missed querySelector. Thanks anyway